# Module name to use for auth0-lock-passwordless?

Tags: auth0

using  angular
    .module('myApp',
      [module1name, module2name,...]), I can't seem to get angular to find auth0-lock-passwordless (installed via `bower_components/auth0-lock-passwordless`.  I've tried a variety of names, but it's not clear what to use... it's not auth0.lockPasswordless, auth0.lock-passwordless, auth0.lock-Passwordless, apparently...

I'm sure this is a trivial thing.

thx

Answer (score 0):

OK - it turns out you don't need to inject the module here... is available already by virtue of the js being included.